# React js - On right click open in new tab of mouse it opens multiple tab when, used window.open()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, window

I am using navigation like this in the react js functional component

trying to work open in a new tab using _blank window open, and also wanted to replicate the same behavior for the right click open in a new tab, I have tried multiple options and combinations as per below

I have tried to add a component-specific event listener as well, might tried bad combinations
Thanks in advance!

```js
const preventEventBubbling = event => {
        
        if (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
    };
    
        const a = document.createElement('a');
        a.target = '_blank';
        a.href = url;
        a.click();
        window.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => preventEventBubbling(event));
        window.history.back();
        return null;
    
    return <iframe title={title} src={url || urls.default} />;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

_blank will copy the current behavior and open in a new tab.

you can try this,
Handle right-click and pass this a.target = '_self';
and for click pass a.target = '_blank'